# Linux: Locating text file from a string input

Tags: files, search

I have started to use Linux and I'm practicing using/making codes to locate and do things. I need code that locates any file from a string of input.

Comment: can you give a sample of what you expect ? have you check `grep` e.g. man grep ?

Comment: Could I just ask what does man grep do?

Comment: It explains how to use grep (unix utility that search the content of a file), I was unsure what you were looking for.

Comment: `man command` will give you the manual of `command`. Grep is a command that searches for strings within files, not sure how it's relevant here. You are looking for `locate` or `find`.

Comment: @user3181367 - is this homework? It's OK if it is, just make that clear when you're asking your Q's.

Comment: No I don't go to school. I'm trying to learn how to use Linux and my friend told me to learn how to program this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options

- `find`. e.g. `find ~/Documents -name '*finances*'`
- `locate` (requires up to date index with `updatedb`). e.g. `locate finances`

to put this in a script, you can do

```
#!/bin/bash

# pattern="${1}" # first argument to script
# alternatively, ask user
echo "Enter a pattern to be searched for in the current directory"
read pattern    

# search current directory `.`
matches=$(find . -type f -name "${pattern}")

# $matches is now a list of matching files
echo "$matches"
```

careful about *shell gobbing*, i.e. a `*` in the pattern is firstly expanded by bash to match filenames in the current directory.

The multitude of options to `find` is documented: `man find`.

Welcome to Linux!

Comment: Ok I'll try that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This program needs an input from the user about what the text file is called

Comment: The program will then report whether it exists

Comment: ok, to read user inputs, use `read pattern` instead of accepting the `${1}`

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please insert this into the code as I'm not sure where this could be.

Comment: try to run the script I provided. It already asks the user to input a string, which is then searched for. again, be careful about wildcards.